# Помоги с xpath соседом

Tags: xpath

Привет всем у меня имеется такая верстка сайта и я хочу получить доступ к элементу с @class product-grid через XPATH, но при этом учесть условия что я не попаду туда если сосед имеет класс category-grid
Иначе говоря пройти в product-grid  если нет соседа category-grid

```
<div class="page-body">
    <div class="category-grid"><span>Есть категория</span></div>
    <div class="product-selectors"></div>
    <div class="product-filters"></div>
    <div class="product-grid">
        <div>..Не должен найти..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> //div[1][@class='product-selectors' or
>   contains(@class,'slider-wrapper') or
>   contains(@class,'category-description')]/parent::div/div[contains(@class,'product-grid')]

Я использовал такую конструкцию  и это работает однако не всегда эти элементы на первом месте

```
<div class="page-body">
    <div class="slider-wrapper"><span></span></div>
    <div class="product-selectors"></div>
    <div class="product-filters"></div>
    <div class="product-grid">
        <div>..Должен найти..</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page-body">
    <div class="slider-wrapper"><span></span></div>
    <div class="category-grid"><span>Есть категория</span></div>
    <div class="product-filters"></div>
    <div class="product-grid">
        <div>..Не Должен найти..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищем  `div[contains(@class,'product-grid')` и проверяем что нет соседа `div[@class='category-grid']`

```
//div[contains(@class,'product-grid') and not(../div[@class='category-grid'])]
```

Comment: Спасибо это работает